# Error parsing NEOS solution file in Pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, neos-server

I wrote a very simple model in Pyomo environment and added the following
two commands at the end.

```
solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory('neos')
results = solver_manager.solve(model, opt='cplex')
```

It returns the following error when I run the code:

> ERROR: Error parsing NEOS solution file  NEOS log: Job 10044842
> dispatched password: MXusJYWF ---------- Begin Solver Output
> ----------- Condor submit: 'neos.submit' Condor submit: 'watchdog.submit' Job submitted to NEOS HTCondor pool.

I know that this is due to Neos's recent requirement of an email address with jobs submitted to NEOS, but how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since January 8 of 2021, Neos require a valid email address for all submissions. First of all, you must sign-up in: https://neos-server.org/neos/index.html

After that, you must upgrade a file in the Pyomo directory (in my case is ../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages), later you look for this path pyomo/neos/ and you must update the file kestrel.py with this file https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/neos/kestrel.py

When you upgrade the file, put a valid e-mail in 224 line of kestrel.py file.

Answer (score 3):

An added note to what Alvaro Avendano has said. Edit kernel.py before line 231, i.e. the line that writes *email = os.environ.get('NEOS_EMAIL', ''))*, with the following:

```
 os.environ['NEOS_EMAIL'] = '<<you email address>>'
```